# Saving e-mails from outlook with Powershell

Tags: powershell, email, outlook

I have a small and easy application which saves e-mails in the file system. This application is used to store project documentation together with the relevant mail messages. At a certain point I used the function:

```
 $Mail.SaveAs($Filename)
```

This works quite fine, however when the function encounters an e-mail with many recipients, it fails.

Is there some parameter I have to setup or should I use a different function to copy this message to the file system ? With drag & drop I do not have any problem. I feel the problem arises with the DOM model, since for every recipient a whole full featured DOM object is created. The failure is proceeded by kind of timeout of the application.

Comment: How many recipients is "many"? There is a limit of 100 receipts per email in Outlook as far as I know.

Comment: more than 400. Sometimes the distribution list contains several hundred persons.

Comment: @TobyU - there is no such limit.

Comment: Does it make a different if you specify the format type? Try to use OlMsgUnicode (= 9) as the second parameter

Comment: Are you able to save the message through Outlook? i.e. Outlook UI essentially uses the same DOM object to do it's processing, so if you can't do it using the UI, you won't be able to do it script wise.

Comment: Can we see the exact error you get?

Comment: Sure, here is the error message:   Exception calling "SaveAs" with "1" argument(s): "There is not enough free memory to run this program. Quit one or more programs, and then try again."
At C:\Users\rv33100\Documents\PowerShell\Tests\Tests_Current\Mail\TestReadingMail0.ps1:123 char:10
+          $Mail.SaveAs($MailFileName)
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

Comment: BTW, yes, from outlook I can save the message

Comment: when I use the second parameter the error message changes, it says Exception calling SaveAs with 2 arguments.

Comment: The workaround I am using actually is to look at the number of recepients, when this number is higher than a certain value (for example 200) the mail get skipped and a nice is generated. This could copied by hand. Kinda quick and dirty bugfix.